# How to read a .py without Python

Tags: python, tkinter, usb

I am a beginner in programming (and in English) and I had to bring a USB key at school, because I had a homework to do. But I don't know how can I read a `.py` file on my teacher's computer, because there's no Python on it.

So how can I do? Thank you if you try to help me.

PS: I use tkinter and pygame on my code

PS #2: you can help me in french, it can be easier.

PS #3: it s a good game console ! lmao

Comment: You need python in some respect, whether thats online or on the usb with the code is up to you

Comment: You can compile a python program to an executable, then it will run on a computer without python.

Comment: If you need to read the content, just open the .py file with another text editor. If you need to run the file, you can convert the .py file to .exe (there are many tutorials that explain how to do it). You can use Pyinstaller or Cx_Freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the python file into an executable and then run it on another computer.

Open the default terminal and type `pip install pyinstaller`
Then, go to the location where your python file is there and type:
`pyinstaller --onefile -w file_name.py`
This will create a single file. If you don't want it, just remove the `--onefile` flag.

The `-w` flag removes the console window. You can remove the flag if you want the console to display.

Also, if you want an icon for the file, use `--icon="path_to_icon.ico"` flag.

For more info:
https://www.pyinstaller.org/

---

French Translation (by Google):

Vous devez convertir le fichier python en un exécutable, puis l'exécuter sur un autre ordinateur.

Ouvrez le terminal par défaut et tapez `pip install pyinstaller`
Ensuite, allez à l'emplacement où se trouve votre fichier python et tapez :
`pyinstaller --onefile -w nom_fichier.py`
Cela créera un seul fichier. Si vous ne le souhaitez pas, supprimez simplement le drapeau `--onefile`.

Le drapeau `-w` supprime la fenêtre de la console. Vous pouvez supprimer l'indicateur si vous souhaitez que la console s'affiche.

De plus, si vous voulez une icône pour le fichier, utilisez l'indicateur `--icon="path_to_icon.ico"`.

Pour plus d'informations:
https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Answer (score 1):

To run python locally, you **need** Python on the computer or USB. But there are a lot of free online tools that allow you to run python. You can log in with a browser and run the program online (it might be a bit slow). It would be easier if you can use IPython in Jupyter notebooks to run your game. I once used https://cocalc.com/ for a different purpose.

Comment: note that browser interpreters don't support some libraries like `tkinter` who need a display (or do they support?)

Comment: It is possible to use tkinter in a browser with CoCalc.  This is because I wrote a web frontend for the xpra X11 server.   See https://doc.cocalc.com/x11.html for instructions.  In particular, click +New --> Linux Graphical X11 Desktop, then in the terminal type "python", load your code (or just "python foo.py"), and the result can use tkinter or anything else like that.  I'm not aware of any other web-based Python environments except cocalc that offer full graphics support.